# python and java encrypt with AES, but the result are not same

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

java code:

```
public String encrypt (String str,String key) throws EncryptException {

    try{
        javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec keyspec = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        javax.crypto.Cipher c = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec);
        byte[] src = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] encrypt = c.doFinal(src);
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypt).replaceAll("\r|\n", "");
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new EncryptException("Encrypt failed.",e);
    }
}
```

python code:

```
def get_enctypted(self, param_req):
    BS = AES.block_size
    pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
    param_json = json.dumps(param_req)
    IV = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(self.get_key(), AES.MODE_ECB, IV)
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(pad(param_json))
    encrypted_base64 = base64.b64encode(IV + encrypted)
    return encrypted_base64
```

when I run the code with the same key and string, I get two different result, anyone know why?

Comment: Can you add what libraries you are using? Also, I am curious if IV is same between different runs of the program. Can you run the python program multiple time and check if the output matches.

Comment: IV is not same between different runs. I also try IV = '\0' * AES.block_size. the output also not matches.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this line - `IV = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)`. You use a `random` value, so of course the results can't be the same.